# Remove Column Name ( Export mysql to CSV )

Tags: php

I have this code and it exports mysql to csv already.

But it also export column names of the table.

I want to remove the names of the columns.

Which part should i remove or rewrite?

```
    <?php
    include('connection.php');

    //header to give the order to the browser
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=exported-books.csv');

    //select table to export the data
    $select_table=mysql_query('select accessionnumber,datereceived,author,booktittle,bookcategory,format,callnumber,isbn,publisher,photo,barcodeid,times,addedby from books');
    $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_table);

    if ($rows)
    {
    getcsv(array_keys($rows));
    }
    while($rows)
    {
    getcsv($rows);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_table);
    }

    // get total number of fields present in the database
    function getcsv($no_of_field_names)
    {
    $separate = '';


    // do the action for all field names as field name
    foreach ($no_of_field_names as $field_name)
    {
    if (preg_match('/\\r|\\n|,|"/', $field_name))
    {
    $field_name = '' . str_replace('', $field_name) . '';
    }
    echo $separate . $field_name;

    //sepearte with the comma
    $separate = ',';
    }

    //make new row and line
    echo "\r\n";
    }
    ?>
```

tia

Comment: Show an example of what it currently returns.

Comment: accessionnumber,datereceived,author,booktittle,bookcategory,format,callnumber,isbn,publisher,photo,barcodeid,times,addedby
1,2014-12-10,saafv,qsadfsa,Technology (Applied Science),Serial,1241,sadfasf,sadgda,Blue hills.jpg,2014-00000001,,ges

it shows table columns as well please help

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;

function getcsv($no_of_field_names) {
 $separate = '';

 foreach ($no_of_field_names as $field_name) {
  if($i > 0) {
   if (preg_match('/\\r|\\n|,|"/', $field_name)) {
    $field_name = '' . str_replace('', $field_name) . '';
   }
   echo $separate . $field_name;

   $separate = ',';
  }
  $i++;
 }

 //make new row and line
 echo "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: which part should i replace? sorry nooby :(

Comment: i have replaced it from function getcsv($no_of_field_names) but it shows error on the csv file

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  str_replace() expects at least 3 parameters

Comment: Woah. Timegap. I'm not even sure what this code was meant to do. This was copied straight from OP's answer.